# Compare values between nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

I am trying to compare the last value inside two seperate lists with matching names. For example: `[(('Matching Name', '2015-06-25', 25.37), ('Matching Name', '2018-08-09', 74.66))]` I want to extract the percentage change from 25.37 to 74.66, through every nested list with matching names inside the [] bracket.

Example input data:

```
>  "(('', '2015-06-25', 25.37), ('', '2018-08-09', 74.66))","(('A',
> '2008-12-26', 10.38), ('A', '2019-04-29', 77.33))","(('AA',
> '2016-11-01', 22.92), ('AA', '2019-04-29', 26.85))","(('AAL',
> '2008-12-26', 7.1), ('AAL', '2019-04-29', 33.77))","(('AAMC',
> '2012-12-13', 15.), ('AAMC', '2019-04-29', 9.94))"
```

Comment: Are the source data sorted? If they are not sorted, this method will not work...

Comment: Yes the data is sorted

Comment: Can you highlight what is going wrong?  It's clear what you want to do and there's some code you've written to do it, but what is stopping you from getting the result you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org) is a good third-party tool to use for this:

```
raw = [
    ('', '2015-06-25', 25.37), ('', '2018-08-09', 74.66),
    ('A', '2008-12-26', 10.38), ('A', '2019-04-29', 77.33),
    ('AA', '2016-11-01', 22.92), ('AA', '2019-04-29', 26.85),
    ('AAL', '2008-12-26', 7.1), ('AAL', '2019-04-29', 33.77),
    ('AAMC', '2012-12-13', 15.), ('AAMC', '2019-04-29', 9.94)
]


import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(raw, columns=['symbol', 'date', 'value'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.sort_values( ['symbol', 'date'] )

grouped = dict(list(df.groupby('symbol')))
for symbol, performance in grouped.items():
    print('')
    print(symbol)
    print(performance.drop(columns=['symbol']).diff())
```

Output is as follows:

```
''
       date  value
0       NaT    NaN
1 1141 days  49.29

'A'
       date  value
2       NaT    NaN
3 3776 days  66.95

'AA'
      date  value
4      NaT    NaN
5 909 days   3.93

'AAL'
       date  value
6       NaT    NaN
7 3776 days  26.67

'AAMC'
       date  value
8       NaT    NaN
9 2328 days  -5.06
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a dictionary, where the keys are the 'matching name' and the values are a list of last values, then perform the computation on each value for a given key.

It is not clear what data structure you have, but you can modify the code if different from the assumed structure below.

In the code below, start by reducing the list to only tuple of 'name' and 'price'.

```
from collections import defaultdict

the_list = [(
    ('', '2015-06-25', 25.37), ('', '2018-08-09', 74.66),
    ('A', '2008-12-26', 10.38), ('A', '2019-04-29', 77.33),
    ('AA','2016-11-01', 22.92), ('AA', '2019-04-29', 26.85),
    )] 

reduced_list = [(x,z) for tick in the_list for x,y,z in tick]
print(reduced_list) 
# [('', 25.37), ('', 74.66), ('A', 10.38), ('A', 77.33), ('AA', 22.92), ('AA', 26.85)]
```

Then create a dictionary where the key is name and value is a list of prices

```
# Map all 'Matching Name', where the dict key is 'Matching Name' 
# and dict value is a list of last values
tickDict = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in reduced_list:
    tickDict[key].append(val)

print(tickDict)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'': [25.37, 74.66], 'A': [10.38, 77.33], 'AA': [22.92, 26.85]})
```

Finally you can compute perform your computation, such as computing the change:

```
# Compute percentage change
ratio = {key: tickDict[key][1]/tickDict[key][0]-1 for key in tickDict}
print(ratio)
# {'': 1.9428458809617655, 'A': 6.449903660886319, 'AA': 0.17146596858638752}
```